Numbered theorem environment problem
I am currently trying to work with theorem environment and labelling the theorems correctly, yet I cannot solve this issue: Here is my minimal working code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe} [section]

\begin{document}
\section{$\sigma$-Algebren und Borelsche Mengen}
\subsection{Inhaltsproblem und Maßproblem}
\subsection{Bezeichnungen und mengentheoretische Grundlagen}

\begin{aufgabe}
    Limes superior und Limes inferior einer Folge von Mengen ändern sich nicht, wenn man in der Folge nur endlich viele Glieder abändert, weglässt oder hinzufügt.
\end{aufgabe}
\end{document}

I then get Aufgabe 1.1 but instead I want Aufgabe 2.1. If I were to write
\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe} [subsection]
I would get Aufgabe 1.2.1 which I also do not want. So basically I want the first number in Aufgabe xy to be the second number of the subsections but it should restart the numbering-process every section.
Can somebody help?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

How are your readers supposed to distinguish between the first Aufgabe in section 1 subsection 2, which would be numbered 2.1, from the first Aufgabe in section 3 subsection 2, which would receive number 2.1 again?

Ok I will add that the next time!

They cannot I am working with a book which follows this scheme and I do not want to change it for readability of the book.

You can modify the appearance of the counter aufgabe by redefining the command \theaufgabe. If I understand correctly, you want the counter to appear as
<subsection number>.<aufgabe number>

and to get this you can use
\renewcommand{\theaufgabe}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{aufgabe}}

Keeping the [subsection] argument in \newtheorem will ensure that the counter is reset at each subsection.
Here's a complete example. I added other theorem statements to make the numbering more obvious.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{aufgabe}{Aufgabe}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\theaufgabe}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{aufgabe}}

\begin{document}

\section{$\sigma$-Algebren und Borelsche Mengen}
\subsection{Inhaltsproblem und Maßproblem}

\begin{aufgabe}
    Limes superior und Limes inferior einer Folge von Mengen ändern sich nicht, wenn man in der Folge nur endlich viele Glieder abändert, weglässt oder hinzufügt.
\end{aufgabe}

\subsection{Bezeichnungen und mengentheoretische Grundlagen}

\begin{aufgabe}
    Limes superior und Limes inferior einer Folge von Mengen ändern sich nicht, wenn man in der Folge nur endlich viele Glieder abändert, weglässt oder hinzufügt.
\end{aufgabe}
\begin{aufgabe}
    Limes superior und Limes inferior einer Folge von Mengen ändern sich nicht, wenn man in der Folge nur endlich viele Glieder abändert, weglässt oder hinzufügt.
\end{aufgabe}
\end{document}


Thank you, that's it!
